# Swift NSMutableAttributedString causes +[CATransaction synchronize] called within transaction

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

```
let TipNovice: Novica = NovicaBackend.novica! as! Novica
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Novica", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell_Novica
        cell.message = NovicaBackend

        let htmlString = "<style>body {font-family: Raleway-Light; font-size: 15;}</style>\(TipNovice.body)"

        let encodedData = htmlString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf16)!
        let attributedOptions = [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType]

        let attributedString = try! NSMutableAttributedString(data: encodedData, options: attributedOptions, documentAttributes: nil)

        let paragraphstyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        paragraphstyle.lineSpacing = 3
        attributedString.addAttribute(NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, value: paragraphstyle, range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length))
        CATransaction.commit()
        cell.Novica_opis.attributedText = attributedString
```

I need help with +[CATransaction synchronize] called within transaction error that i get when this code is runed. More precisely the only line that is causing the problem is the

```
let attributedString = try! NSMutableAttributedString(data: encodedData, options: attributedOptions, documentAttributes: nil)
```

All of this code is running in this TableView funcion.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem where calling `NSAttributedString` within `viewDidLoad()` or even `viewWillAppear()` caused `+[CATransaction synchronize]` to occur. I fixed it by putting the appropriate call to `NSAttributedString` into the main queue to be executed at different point in time.

Like:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.textField.attributedText = attributedStringFromHtmlString(infoMessage)
}
```

Note: `attributedStringFromHtmlString` is a wrapper function calling `NSAttributedString`

See also [github](https://github.com/facebook/componentkit/issues/235) for a similar issue.

Comment: For us, this caused `collectionView(didSelectItemAt:)` to be executed, wrapping it as suggested fixed it.